# how do I loop something in the form for(a!:b){loop}

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to loop into an arrayList of Users a user which is not already in the loop and adding to the list. is it possible to loop with a for each loop?

```
public boolean addUser(User u)
    {
        boolean valid=false;
        for (u not in : users )
        {
            users.add(u);
            valid = true;
        }
               return valid; 
    }
```

Comment: first of all, this code will not compile. second, it does not make much sense - if you are adding inside the loop, it means you are performing add as many times as there are items in the loop

Comment: Do you only want to add the user if the user isn't in the list already?

Comment: `if(!users.contains(u)) { users.add(u) }` not sure why you need to do a for loop when the array list provides the functionality

Comment: @SharonBenAsher you are right the code does not compile I was trying to add user to the list if it is not already in the list already

Comment: oh I will give it a try thank you

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that I dont need a for Loop...instead I can use

```
 public boolean addUser(User u)
{
    boolean valid=false;
    if(!users.contains(u))
    {
        users.add(u);
        valid = true;
    }
           return valid; 
}
```